# Sharing LINUX NFS Folder on Windows Server

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, sql-server, nfs

I have some CSV files on Linux. I would like to load them into my SQL Server with a stored procedure. I'm looking for a way to share the files via NFS with my Windows Server. I was wondering if anybody can help me describe the process.

I'm a completely newbie to this so I apologize for any mistakes of mine in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. install /configure NFS server on Linux box.
2. Export the directory / mount containing the files
3. Install / configure Services for NFS on the Windows Server  (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753302(v=ws.10).aspx)
4. Use the nfsclient installed on 3 to mount the directory exported in 2.

Another option would be to install/Configure SAMBA on the linux box, and then make the directory available via CIFS.  It has the benefit on not needing to install extra software on the windows side, but if you already have existing NFS infrastructure it does add another dependency on the Linux side.